# node js mongodb ObjectID constractor usage

Tags: node.js, mongodb

using the official MongoDB driver for NodeJS, i extracted docs using the find({}) method, when attempting to update one of these docs with updateOne({_id: doc._id}, ... ) it does nothing, i have found out that i need to use {_id: new ObjectID(doc_id)} in order to successfully update. i do not understand the idea behind this, doc._id is something i extracted directly from the db, what changed in the proccess that makes it unmatched to the _id in the db? also, i have managed to successfully find docs using {_id: doc._id} without the ObjectID constructor, only the updateOne method doesn't work. what's the logic behind the ObjectID constructor? do i need to use it every time i communicate with the database using id's i extracted from it? for example if i want to insert doc._id as a property of another document.

edit: here's the relevant part of the code:

```
db.collection('students')
    .insertOne(poolStudent, (err, docs)=>{
        if(err){throw new Error(err)}
        cb(docs.ops[0]) //where i get the student entity from
})

db.collection('students')
    .updateOne({_id: student._id}, 
        {$set: {rating: student.rating}}, function(err, r) {
            if(err){console.log(err)}
            console.log(r.result.n, r.result.nModified) //0, 0
})
```

Comment: Any ObjectID value returned as part of a document can be directly used in another query so something's off here. Can you show your `find` and `updateOne` code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: are you sure student._id is a valid MongoID?

Comment: Are you connecting on the same database in which you are looking manually?

Comment: found out what causes the problem, i was doing student = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(student)) at some point, and while a console.log of the id looks the same before and after, the database no longer matches it to the id in the server for some reason.